# How do I access the pixels of an image using OpenCV-Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I want to know how to loop through all pixels of an image. I tried this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0,5,(500,500))
img = cv2.imread('D:\Project\Capture1.jpg',0)
p = img.shape
print p
rows,cols = img.shape

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        k = x[i,j]
        print k
```

It prints a vertical set of numbers which is not in the form of an array. I am also getting an array out of bounds exception. Please suggest a method.

Answer (score 35):

I don't see what's the purpose of your x variable. You don't need it.

Simply use:

```py
img = cv2.imread('/path/to/Capture1.jpg',0)
rows,cols,_ = img.shape

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        k = img[i,j]
        print(k)
```

which will print indeed a vertical set of numbers. If you want to modify the values of the pixels use `img.itemset()`. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html

If you want to print the whole array then use `print(img)`

Comment: Hi, I know this has been a long time, I have a question regarding vertical set of numbers. Is it because it's grayscale that's why it's printing one individual value vertically?

Comment: @Darkgenius007 Passing `flag=0` to `imread(..., flag)` is the `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` flag. For color, you will want to pass `IMREAD_COLOR` which is 1, eg. `imread("img.jpg", 1)`.

Comment: And use `rows,cols,_ = img.shape` instead.

Answer (score 21):

**Access specific pixel in Python**

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
pixel= image[200, 550]
print pixel
```

*output:* [ 73  89 102]

Comment: `pixel_b, pixel_g, pixel_r = image[row][column]`

Answer (score 6):

Accessing using array index will be slow with a numpy array.

You can use the `item()` method for access and `itemset` for performing changes.

For example

```
for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,img.shape[1]):
        pixel = img.item(i, j)
        print pixel
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imagename = "capure.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(imagename, 0) # 0 params, for gray image
height, width = img.shape[:2]  # image height and width
print(img)  # all image pixels value in array
print(img[10, 10])  # one pixel value in 10,10 coordinate

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        print(img[y,x], end = "\t")
    print("\t")
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way to extract image pixel (r,g,b) value is by using numpy.ndindex():

- Which will take h,w or h,w,c (height, width, channel) of an image to traverse

For example, code snippet is below and np.ndindex is only using height and width:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("cat.jpg") 
for i, j in np.ndindex(image.shape[:-1]): #image.shape = (150,150)
    print(image[i,j])
```

Now the output will be r,g,b values, which will be as follows:

```
[ 54  97 231]
[ 63 105 241]
[ 67 109 245]
[ 71 115 250]
[ 79 125 255]
[ 81 130 255]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import Image

image = Image.open("example.png")
image_data = np.asarray(image)

for i in range(len(image_data)):
    for j in range(len(image_data[0])):
        print(image_data[i][j])  # this row prints an array of RGB color for each pixel in the image
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the pixel values in an array **'k'** by going through loop.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sample.jpg',0)
rows,cols = img.shape
k = []
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        k.append(img[i,j])
print k
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
  for (int y = 0; y<im.rows; y++) 
    {

  for (int x = 0; x<im.cols; x++)
    {
        Vec3b color = im.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
        //you can print color this has the pixel value

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vertical array are the RGB (Reg, Green, Blue) channel values for the image. If you want a single value for the pixel you may want to convert the image to grayscale first. It really depends on your application and what you want to do with the image, converting to grayscale is just one approach.

To convert to grayscale

```
grayImg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Some basic operations are shown in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html)

Comment: It is BGR in that order, not RGB as you say. Note, that when converting to grayscale, constant is XXX_*BGR*2GRAY

Answer (score 0):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np 

image = cv2.imread('/path/to/test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

for x in range (1,480):
    for y in range (1,640):
        pixel = image[x,y]
        print(pixel)
```

Comment: Could you explain why is this the solution ? what did the OP miss, and what does he need to know in order to understand this solution ?

Comment: images are 0 indexed

Answer (score 0):

you are reading image in gray scale

img = cv2.imread('D:\Project\Capture1.jpg',0)

here you will only get intencity

Comment: How does this answer the question?